# xmodmap: remapped Control_L not working for copying and pasting

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

After spending hours, I found that `xmodmap` can be used to remap <kbd>/</kbd> key to <kbd>Left Control</kbd> key. I used following command:

```
 $ xmodmap -e "keycode 94 =  Control_L NoSymbol Control_L"
```

Using `xev`, I find that `keycode 94` is the <kbd>/</kbd> key on which I want to remap.

But now this <kbd>/</kbd> key (`keycode 94`) is not working as <kbd>Control</kbd> key or even as <kbd>/</kbd> key. Any shortcut like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> is not working.

How can I make this key work as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key properly?

I am using Linux Mint.

Answer (score 0):

Modifiers like Control are somewhat special. The general procedure is something like:

```
clear control

! ...

keycode 94 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L

! ...

add control = Control_L
add control = Control_R
```

You should place these lines in a file, say `~/.xmodmaprc`, and call `xmodmap ~/.xmodmaprc`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I could not understand what does this mean. I am very new to Linux. I tried to put "Clear control" in terminal and it gave an error. Can you please elaborate